# How to stop YouTube sound playing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

I have a YouTube video popup. When I click on the button, the popup appears. But when I close it the sound of the video keeps playing. 
How can I stop the sound?

```
function popup2(id, video) {
    $('.popup_overlay').show();
    $('#'+id).addClass('activePopup');
    $('.activePopup').show();
    switch(video) {
        case 'video1': $('#video').html('<iframe width="854" height="510" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/kJUmm8-Y5JM?autoplay=1&cc_load_policy=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'); break;
    }
}

function popup_out() {
    $('.popup_overlay').hide();
    $('.popup').hide();
    $('.popup_overlay').hide();
    $('.popup2').hide();
    $('.popup').removeClass('activePopup');
    $('body').find('label').removeClass('red');
    send = false;
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="popup2" id="video"></div>

<div onclick="popup2('video', 'video1')">BUTTON</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are just hiding the youtube iframe, so the video is still playing but you can't see it.
You could try to just empty the #video div in your popup_out() function, something like this:

```
$('#video').html('');
```

or

```
$('#video').empty();
```

Comment: Ok man, but how to use your code? ) Could you please explain me =)

Comment: I assume function popup_out() is used to close the popup. Just add $('#video').empty(); to that function